# Unity3D 5.2.1f1 causing Android app to crash

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I just upgraded to Unity 5.2 hoping it would fix an issue with triggers not working correctly in Android. After upgrading I built the Android and deployed it. Now the app will not run. 
I get this error

> Unfortunately, [Game Name] has stopped

I tried looking at logcat but it doesn't help. I'm at a total loss as to what could have changed. 
I double checked the Device Filter and it's set to FAT (ARMv7+x86).

Comment: From what Version did you upgrade into?

Comment: version 5.1. Which had worked fine

Comment: There is not much of a change from that version. So I suggest for you to back up, and Delete the Meta Data's that it Have from the old version. So how would you know which one is the old version? You don't have to know, just delete everything. Then Relaunch the project in the new version and Retry to compile. The only major problem from 5.1 to 5.2 is the Path Bake navigation, which I think is not your case. As it will still make the application run.

Comment: I tried deleting all the .meta files but it didn't fix it. Broken YAML file(Assets/Standard Assets/2D/Animator/2dCharacterAnimator.controller). Local file identifier (110283043) doesn't exist! and Broken YAML file(Assets/Standard Assets/2D/Animator/2dCharacterAnimator.controller). Local file identifier (110232664) doesn't exist!

Comment: Lol, it means that you have used a package in your project. That the Old Unity 3d Have. If so, get that file from the old Project. Mostly if it is obsolete. I would like to inform you that most of the Standard assets is not supported anymore because of the fast Change on the Platform. For example. I used the 3dCharacter controller before and the Animation Legacy Script in the Standard Assets. It was removed. So make sure you get it. Those files are just Scripts, you can re- download them.